# How to redirect to a page according to URL parameter in php?

Tags: php, function, superglobals

I am working on project in php where I want to create parameter in main index page and redirect page according to the parameter
Example: 
if URL is "index.php?page=about.php"
the page shoudld be redirected to about.php

My code

```
function get_parameter(){
$page = $_GET['page'];
header("Location : ".$page".php");
}
```

I want to try it here

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['userId'])): ?>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=login">Sign In</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=register">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So how do i make the function working?
thankyou

Comment: Look into `$_GET['page']`  ---  Other than that .. Show us what you've tried, and we can help you fix it.  Not much to go on without code.

Comment: Look at the [PHP manual, specifically the page on `header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: `header("Location: $_GET[page]");`

Comment: Check the code, edited!!

Comment: But how do i redirect according to the link clicked

Comment: You do know that PHP will expand $variables automatically when placed within a double quoted string?

Comment: Looks like all you would have to do is actually CALL the function you wrote called `get_parameter()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL is "index.php?page=about.php" and `$page = $_GET['page'];` then $page = about.php.

So the code for redirect should be `header("Location: $page");`

Inside "" yo do not have to concatenate with point (.) the php $variables. You have to do that only with '' like: `header('Location: ' . $page . '');`

And do not use a function for redirect. Just read the page from GET and then redirect.

header() will not work if you load html.